# Unexpected LatLng set in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have this line of code in my javascript:

```
console.log(google.maps.LatLng(49.220341,17.649555));
```

And console returns object with google maps Lat and Lng, which is what I expected, but:

Then I'm trying to do this:

```
var start = "49.220341,17.649555";
console.log(google.maps.LatLng(start));
```

But console returns empty object with NaN values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string of the lat/lng pair, but `google.maps.LatLng` expects two strings representing the pair. You will need to use two variables:

```
var lat = 49.220341;
var lng = 17.649555;
console.log(google.maps.LatLng( lat , lng ));
```

or an array:

```
var start = [49.220341,17.649555];
console.log(google.maps.LatLng(start[0],start[1]));
```

I prefer the use of an object, however:

```
var start = ['lat':49.220341,
             'lng':17.649555];
console.log(google.maps.LatLng(start['lat'],start['lng']));
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays.

Comment: @Musa meh my bad, I've been using Python as of late... they are just called objects in JS

Comment: But I got the idea and that's great :) Thanks.

Comment: `google.maps.LatLng` does not expect string arguments, it expects numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Dave is right, the function will only take two arguments, not one. If you want to store them in a string like that, you could always call

```
var start = "49.220341,17.649555";
console.log(google.maps.LatLng(start.substring(0,start.indexOf(",")),start.substring(start.indexOf(",")+1)));
```

or

```
var start = "49.220341,17.649555";
var startArr=start.split(",");
console.log(google.maps.LatLng(startArr[0],startArr[1]));
```

Both of these separate the string around the comma.